# Separate tabs on dock Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

How can I separate tabs for multiple the same applications on dock on Ubuntu 18.04?

For example, in this picture, I want to separate tab terminal to 3 tabs and tab files to 2 tab:

[image: this picture]

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Here is the answer:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/02/alt-tab-display-separate-windows-ubuntu-18-04/ I hope, i can help you

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I assume you are not using a MacBook but if you are, just use the correspondence of any key I will mention in the answer.

For your terminal, use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and for the files when you want to open a new folder on your current file window right-click on the folder and then select "Open in New Tab". Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: it looks like you don't understand me. I mean i want to seperate terminal  icon on the dock to 3 seperate icons and the file icon to 2 seperate file icons